# Background Image won't show in div

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML Code

```css
.jumbotron
    {
     background-image: url("file://C:\xampp\htdocs\CSProject\images\Psi.png");
     height: 250px;
     width: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
     </head>
     
     <body>
      <div class="jumbotron">
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I haven't been able to find any solutions as to why this background image won't show.

Thanks for any help or info.

Comment: Try using relative path, something like: url(images/Psi.png). Assuming your HTML files is under CSProject folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL for `background-image` needs to path from your CSS file, not from your root directory.

So if your CSS file is contained in the folder CSProject, try changing:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("images/Psi.png");
}
```

Comment: The path should have a forward slash, not a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with your image path...like Erez recommended i would use a relative path.

If your HTML code and 'images' folder are within the 'CSProject' folder,  then reference that image like

```
background-image:url('/images/Psi.png');
```

Which brings me to my next point, why is your file-path using backslashes? it should be

```
 /htdocs/CSProject/images/Psi.png
```